# pcm512x charge capacitor value

Tags: capacitor, audio, pcm

First of all I'd like to say that I'm quite new in electronics (I'm a software developer) so I might be missing some basic knowledge for which I apologize.

I'm trying to create a DAC using the PCM5122. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5122.pdf) mentions that the charge pump flying capacitor should be a 2.2uF COG Ceramics (I'm guessing COG should be C0G - C zero G).

Now, I've been to my local electronics dealer and he has never heard of a ceramic capacitor with that value. Also Conrad (where I usually get my stuff) doesn't have one. The only place where I can find such a capacitor (SMD) is at Mouser (which will cost me € 20,- on shipping).

My questions are:

- Why is this so rare?
- Is there a non-SMD variant of this capacitor (I can't find one but maybe I'm not using the correct search terms)?
- Can I use something else in stead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are looking out the "Layout Example" section, where the data sheet has a couple of problems, which you have found!  First, there is no reason for an NPO or COG capacitor on the charge pump; a 2.2 uF X7R will be fine here, since the charge pump is not in the audio circuit.  COG caps are only required on the output filter to prevent the filter roll-off from moving around with temperature.  Second, the output filter cap values (which *should* be NP0) are recommended to be 2.2 nF (much easier to find), not 2.2 uF.  This is mentioned several places elsewhere in the document.  The "Layout Example" is a typo.  Good luck!